# Is mask option not available for Adobe XD windows users?

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

I have been trying to follow an online course on XD and the instructor showed the masking function. But, object button is missing from my Windows version of XD. Shortcut didn't work either. So, does it have a mask option?

Answer (score 3):

**Setup**

To use the "Mask with Shape" feature, make sure you have two elements on your artboard:

1. The base element that you want to apply the mask to
2. The shape that you want to use as your mask

**Masking**

Now that you have both element, select *both* shapes. Then right click and select "Mask with Shape" from the contextual menu.

The shortcuts are:

- Windows: Ctrl + Shift + M
- Mac: Cmd + Shift + M

[This tutorial](https://www.xdguru.com/adobe-xd-guide/masking/) has a nice GIF showing the "Mask with Shape" feature in action.